# How to find all initial values of a given complex sequence, $(z_n)$, such that $(z_n)$ is two-cycle.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm given the sequence $z_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}z_n^2+1$

I'm trying to find all initial values $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $(z_n)$ is two-cycle; i.e. s.t. the even subsequence $\{z_0,z_2,z_4,...\}$ **and** the odd subsequence $\{z_1,z_3,z_5,...\}$ are constant but **not** equal.

Could anyone at least give me a hint towards trying to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: $\left\{z_n\right\}$ is a one-cycle iff $z_0 = z_1$. Expanding $z_1$ using the recurrence gives a quadratic which is easily solved. $\left\{z_n\right\}$ is a two-cycle iff $z_0 = z_2$ and $z_0 \neq z_1$. Expanding $z_0 = z_2$ using the recurrence until the only indeterminate is $z_0$ yields a quartic. However, we know that the two initial values that give one-cycles must be roots of this quartic. Factor them out to get a quadratic. It's roots will give you the two-cycles.

Comment: So all the values of $z_0$ such that the even sequence is two-cycle is $z_{0_{1,2,3,4}}=1 \pm i,-1 \pm i \sqrt{5},$ (solving $z_0=0.5[0.5z_0^2+1]^2+1$)but what should I do for the *odd* subsequence?

Comment: $1 + i$ and $1 - i$ give the one-cycles. $-1 \pm \sqrt{5}i$ give the two-cycles. Try calculating a few values of the sequence starting with one of the values giving a two-cycle. That should help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to do this in general.

For the particular problem we put $z_{2n} = a$ and $z_{2n+1} = b$ and then split the recurence relation in the two parts

$z_{2n+1} = \frac{z_{2n}^2}{2} + 1$

$z_{2n} = \frac{z_{2n-1}^2}{2} + 1$

and insert $a,b$ to get the two equations

$b = \frac{a^2}{2} + 1$ and $a = \frac{b^2}{2} + 1$

which can be solved with solutions $a = -1 \pm \sqrt{5}$ (and $b = -1 \mp \sqrt{5}$).

The method can be generalized. To find an $k$-cycle you first split the recurence relation into the $k$ parts

$z_{kn} = f(z_{kn-1},z_{kn-2},...,z_{kn-k+1})$

$z_{kn+1} = f(z_{kn},z_{kn-1},...,z_{kn-k})$

...

$z_{kn+k-1} = f(z_{kn+k-1},z_{kn+k-2},...,z_{kn})$

and insert $z_{kn+i} = a_i$ for $i=0,1,...,k-1$ to get the equation system for $a_i$.